# How can I do a simple MySQL query in a play framework controller?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

So I have JPA, Hibernate, and etc set up in my Play! Framework application. The database connects and etc., but I do not get at all how to run a simple query on a controller. Could someone provide me a simple controller class that directly executes a query? (Ex. "create table tablename")

I am looking for a Java example.

Comment: not a good idea to execute your query at controller

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look into [official JPA sample](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples/java/computer-database-jpa), you'll find there some sample queries (in models)

Answer (score 0):

below code in **scala** is working in controller, but use model for this

```
 case class City(city: Int, town: Int)
  def userCities(id: String) = Action{
  var info:List[controllers.MyController.City]=List()
  val data=DB.withConnection {
    implicit Connection =>
       val sql = "SELECT city ,town FROM cities WHERE userId=118376027237390  limit 0,1"
       val res = SQL(sql)
  info = res().map(row => City(row[Int]("city"), row[Int]("town"))).toList
  println(info)
  }
   Ok(write(info))
  }
```